# Question about greatest integer function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that $[x+y] \geq [x]+[y]$

This is my work so far:

Let $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$ and suppose that $\{x\}=x-[x]$ and $\{y\}=y-[y]$, based on the definition.  So then $x=[x]+\{x\}$ and $y=[y]+\{y\}$ also.  So then $[x+y]=[[x]+\{x\}+[y]+\{y\}]=[x]+[y]+[\{x\}+\{y\}]$.  And since $[\{x\}+\{y\}] \leq 1, [x+y] \leq [x]+[y]+1$.

From here, can I say that since $[x+y] \leq [x]+[y]+1$, then $[x+y] \geq [x]+[y]$ also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no. You need another inequality.

Since $0\le \{x\}\lt 1,\ 0\le \{y\}\lt 1$, we have
$$0\le \{x\}+\{y\}\lt 2\Rightarrow 0\le [\{x\}+\{y\}]\le 1.$$
Here, using $[\{x\}+\{y\}]\ge 0$ instead of $[\{x\}+\{y\}]\le 1$, we have
$$[x+y]=[x]+[y]+[\{x\}+\{y\}]\ge [x]+[y].$$